# Emacs - Strange Whitespace

Tags: emacs, console, cursor

In console `emacs`, the point becomes more than one character wide almost at random.

Even stranger, it acts as through the leading whitespace is the same color as the point.  That is, if there is more than one leading space, the large point remains where it is rather than returning to the previous line, so it doesn't fully behave like a large point.

On the other hand, if I switch focus to another program, the point will look like wide hollow box.  I'll try to illustrate how it looks with Unicode:

**Focused:**

```
██████ <-- Like point, but wider.
```

**Unfocused:**

```
[    ] <-- Fully-enclosed hollow box, like regular terminal cursor when unfocused.
```

I could only really reproduce the behavior by pressing space multiple times, and the point would become 2 wide every 4-5 spaces.  It also occurs sporadically after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, adding, and then deleting a character.

Please let me know if there is any other info that may be relevant or to somehow elaborate, since I have no clue what might be affecting `emacs` like this.

Comment: Is it reproducable with `emacs -nw -q`?

Comment: Use `C-u C-x =` to see what's under the cursor.

Comment: @abo-abo Yes, it still occurs with `emacs -nw -q`.  I only briefly mentioned it, but I think I am using `emacs -nw` already.  I don't have the X version of emacs installed.

Comment: @angus If I press space until it occurs, the minibuffer reads `point=7 of 6 (EOB) column=6` after your mentioned key combo.  After adding one or more spaces and trying it again over the wide area, all of the spaces under it are indeed space characters (ASCII 20).

Comment: It's probably caused by your terminal, then. What terminal emulator are you using? Try asking also at http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: That looks like it might be the case.  I use urxvt (rxvt-unicode), but I couldn't reproduce the behavior with lxterminal or, interestingly, with tmux in urxvt.  I'll ask on Unix & Linux now, thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [a solution from an ArchLinux forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1018150#p1018150).

To easily fix, either add the switch `+ptab` when starting `urxvt` or add `urxvt*pastableTabs: false` to your .Xresources.